# Splitting data from the same column in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I am working on an SQL project and I am fairly new to SQL.

In the problem, there are accounts that are registered and accounts that aren't. What is the correct syntax to filter all of the registered ones onto one side and the non-registered one on the other side.

I am trying to make it look like two different columns.

Comment: What have you tried, and what is the structure of these tables? Also, what do you mean when you say "registered ones on one side"? Do you want two queries to split the dataset, or do you want all registered accounts first, followed by the anonymous ones?

Comment: Sorry it is a little unclear. This is what I have so far.


`SELECT name AS BankName, 
  COUNT( DISTINCT num_trans) AS NumberOfTransactions,
  SUM( DISTINCT spend) AS TotalSpent,
  registered AS Registered
FROM bank
WHERE name LIKE '%bank1_201001%'
GROUP BY name,registered
UNION ALL
SELECT name AS BankName, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT num_trans) AS NumberOfTransactions,
  SUM(DISTINCT spend) AS TotalSpent,
  registered AS Registered
FROM bank
WHERE name LIKE '%bank2_201001%'
GROUP BY name, registered`


When I run it, it has a column for registered, but I am trying

Comment: to make a registered column with the banks that are registered underneath, and then have a non-registered column with those banks underneath of it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your edit, you're well on your way already. The missing part seems to be catching the banks that are registered in the first query, and the non-registered ones for the second query.

To do so, you can use a `WHERE` clause on the `registered` column to only grab those you want, like so (assuming registered will contain 1 for registered and 0 for unregistered:

```
...
WHERE 
   name LIKE '%bank1_201001%' 
   AND registered = 1
...
UNION ALL 
...
WHERE 
    name LIKE '%bank2_201001%' 
    AND registered = 0
...
```

That would probably also remove the requirement for having to put in the actual bank name (I'm guessing you're doing that because you know the first one is registered and the second one is not?).

I'm not entirely certain if this is what you need. Particularly the "I'm trying to make a registered column with the banks that are registered underneath it" is kind of confusing. You initially select the name, which would be the bank name. The `Registered` column would then be a boolean column indicating `Yes` or `No` (or `1`" and `0`).

Let me know if this helps?